# Should i get a new kit lens for my 450D or a new body with kit lens altogether?

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, kit-lens, canon-450d

I recently broke my kit lens for my 450D and have been looking into replacements. At the moment i have a 55-250 mm objective as my primary objective since it is all i have at the moment.

My question is mostly based on the fact that i have found the 18-55 IS II lens for ~135$. Meanwhile i've spotted the 1300D with the same kit lens (18-55 IS II) for about ~350$~280£. Is the jump in price worth it for the kit lens only or the whole package?

Comment: Compare the resolutions, dynamic ranges, sensitivities and AF points of both bodies. Compare also their buffer size, processor and other options. If you find the difference worth your money, go for a kit; otherwise buy the lens only.

Comment: Related: [When should I upgrade my camera body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71199/when-should-i-upgrade-my-camera-body)

Answer (score 0):

If you feel you have being limited in the past by:

- Low light situations where you need a better performance, and you whished to take decent photos at ISO 1600 or beyond. (ISO 1,600 vs 128,000) In reality the 120,000 could have too much noise to be usable, but you could find a 6,400 or 12,800 really handy)
- The Mpx. (12 vs 24)
- The number of focus points. (9 vs 19)
- You want to shoot video.

---

And if you really feel your camera is getting a bit too old, or porbably reaching the recomended number of shots.

---

Take a look at: [When should I upgrade my camera body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71199/when-should-i-upgrade-my-camera-body)