# Why buy a Pentax K1-II over Pentax K1?

Tags: dslr, iso, pentax

I have looking for my dream DSLR with sensor shifting thus pure color along with no low pass filter.

I fail to see any differences other than tripled max ISO but why buy the second gen Pentax K1?

They removed the button lights. Is tripled ISO really that important?

Also is there an online reference that says K-1 II have better ISO performance when it comes to grain etc?

I know newer sensors are generally have higher tech quality but why buy a newer camera for it? Are there firmware and heating issue problems that were solved that can't be found in good sites like apotelyt.com?

Comment: Read the reviews, e.g. https://www.dpreview.com/reviews/pentax-k-1-ii-review , since you are the one spending the money.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I upgrade my camera body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71199/when-should-i-upgrade-my-camera-body)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article explicitly discusses the differences between the 2. Whether or not those differences are worth any variation in price is entirely up to you.

https://www.pentaxforums.com/reviews/pentax-k-1-ii-review/introduction.html

> Enter the K-1 Mark II, a new DSLR which is almost identical to its predecessor, but with the inclusion of several new elements:
>
> - A new accelerator unit for improved noise handling at high ISO
> - A Dynamic Pixel Shift mode allowing the capture of handheld pixel shift images
> - Improved AF speed and tracking
> - Increased ISO sensitivity (two stops added, up to ISO 819200)

The Pentax Forums site also offers a side-by-side comparison of features, and it really highlights that there are no differences other than what's listed above.
https://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/pentax-cameras-compared/?c1=Pentax%20K-1%20II&c2=Pentax%20K-1

The Mark II was released 2 years later and wasn't intended to be a huge step up. It was a refresh and this actually resulted in being able to send in your K-1 and have it upgraded to the Mark II with some internal component changes. If you didn't own a K-1 and were shopping, it might make more sense to buy a more newly-manufactured camera. If shopping the used market, then I'd say it comes down to budgeting and what condition you can find the used ones in.