# Strange bands of shadow and light

Tags: nikon, nikon-z6

I have a Nikon Z6.  It's set to Auto.  I have 2 6500K lights on my image, at 45° angles to either side.  These two images show shadow at the bottom in one, and at the top in the other, same exposure, same everything, just two snaps one after the other.  What's happening here?  In the visual display, I can see a band of gray scrolling at a constant rate upwards, like a TV...  Is something wrong with my camera?  What's going on here?  Why am I not getting consistency, shot to shot?  Thanks in advance.

[image: shadow at bottom]
[image: shadow at top]

How can I fix or avoid this issue?

Comment: Perfectly normal when using any non-incandescent type of artificial lighting. (fluorescent, LED, HID, etc) Just use the “anti-flicker” option on your camera, or a slower shutter speed, or change the lighting source.

Comment: @MikeSowsun Ah, thank you.  I'm using Daylight 6500k lamps.

Comment: Are they LED lights?

Comment: You probably used electronic first curtain or full electronic shutter. This will cause banding with certain light sources. It will not occur on full mechanical shutter.

Comment: @KaiMattern If the exposure duration is longer than the rate of the flicker.

Comment: Also related: [Two pictures with the same setting come out with different lighting](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87634/15871) and [LED lighting problem: Bands of uneven exposure on images taken under LED lighting with silent shutter (full electronic shutter)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/121275/15871)

Comment: @MikeSowsun Yes, I'm using 2 Daylight brand 16W daylight LED bulbs.

Comment: @KaiMattern Thanks - I'll experiment with settings for the shutter, and other suggested settings as well.

Comment: @MichaelC Thanks - these links and the other previous Q&As suggested are very helpful.  Thanks All.